# GdalDEM slope error in Jupyter

Tags: gdal, dem, slope, gdaldem

I try to calculate slope data. This is the DEM source https://www.earthenv.org/DEM

Firstly, I translate data with gdal.Warp according to image UTM zone. Original image .bil extension so first I convert to tif and then reproject the image. You can see gdalinfo of this image in below.

[image: gdalinfo of translate dem file]

I try to calculate in Jupyter notebook. 
gdal.DEMProcessing(dest,source,"slope")
I get "ValueError: Received a NULL pointer." 
I try with the same input image in command line and Qgis Slope tool, everything is fine. What I miss it?

Comment: Please post the actual code you used

Comment: I wrote my code. In jupyter  >> gdal.DEMProcessing(dest,source,"slope")

Comment: dest and source are file paths?